# Fill populate arrays from other table

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, array

Things go inside other things.  More than one can go inside and each one can be inside many different containers.  This is for a on-line shopping site where assorted things that we get from our suppliers are bundled together, given a web-page and then sold as that collective.  It all used to be tracked with a bunch of horrible CSV files but I'm setting up a proper database now.

```
create table collections(
    sku character varying(50),
    components text[]);

create table products(
    ordering_id character varying(50),
    inside text[] );
```

*inside*'s elements are *sku*s from *collections* and *components* elements are *ordering_id*s from *products*.

The contents of these easily fill in both columns in the *products* table and sku in *collections*.  Now I want to fill in *components*: preferably with some tricky **SQL** statement.  The best I could come up with is:

```
with new_values as ( select ordering_id, inside from products )
    update collections set components = components ||   
        nv.ordering_id::text  from new_values nv
    where collections.sku::text = any( nv.inside );
```

but that only fills in the first *product* that's found inside each *collections*.  Why is that?  Do I need to do some sort of **JOIN** to get this to work?

Sample data:

**collections**

```
sku    components
10A    {}
20A    {}
```

**products**

```
ordering_id    inside
1234            {10A}
5678            {10A, 20A}
```

should leave *products* unchanged but *collections* should now be

**collections**

```
sku    components
10A    {1234,5678}
20A    {5678}
```

Unfortunately what I get from the **SQL** that I came up with above is

```
sku    components
10A    {1234}
20A    {5678}
```

Comment: Please, add some sample data and the desired result.

Comment: Ok, added them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following aggregates the products as you want it:

```
select c.sku, array_agg(p.ordering_id) as ids
from collections c
  join products p on c.sku = any(p.inside)
group by c.sku;
```

The above returns:

```
sku | ids        
----+------------
10A | {1234,5678}
20A | {5678}
```

Now this can be used as the source of an update statement:

```
update collections 
   set components = t.ids
from (
    select c.sku, array_agg(p.ordering_id) as ids
    from collections c
      join products p on c.sku = any(p.inside)
    group by c.sku
) t
where collections.sku = t.sku;
```

Comment: I figured it had something to do with a JOIN.  My JOIN-fu is weak.